# SQL Server 2014 read only connections not forwarding after reboot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, alwayson

I have a four node SQL Server 2014 (12.0.4416) environment with one node acting as a read only node. When I setup routing, I can use the `applicationintent = readonly` property and everything seems to work. My connections that use `applicationintent` readonly forward to the correct server. Confirmed by running a `select @@servername`.

However, when I disconnect the `readonly` replica from the network or reboot it, the connections now go back to reading from the primary.

Do you have to enable anything to get it working again after a reboot?

Comment: No you don't have to enable anything after a reboot.

Comment: That's what I thought.  It looks as if I was being a bit impatient.  I got up to do something and when I cam back my connection now forwards to the correct replica.

Is there some sort of a time threshold before it finally changes.  It doesn't seem as if it's as soon as SQL Server is ready.